# Win10Pro no longer automatically sees USB drive E:

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive

Drives C: and D: are taken by the hard drive and the DVD.  So the first available drive for a USB stick is E:.  When I plug any USB into the computer, it does not show in File Explorer or in the "My PC" view.  But, if I manually tell Explorer to go to "E:", it works fine.  Also, if I plug a second USB drive into the computer with the first one still in, it immediately shows up in all views as drive F:.  So, only drive E: is not automatically recognized.

Please note:  the USB stick itself is fine and not corrupted; autoplay is enabled and set to open Explorer to view files.  The problem is only in automatically recognizing drive E:.

Another note:  this used to work fine.  At some point, I was given an option to change how it reacted to drive E: and I changed it, but I can't remember what I was asked or what I did.  There must be a setting somewhere to reverse this.

Comment: More info - the drive (E:) shows up in Disk Management as healthy; the latest driver is installed.  Also, if I reverse the order of plugging in USB drives, then the second drive plugged in always shows up correctly as drive F:.  It is only the first drive plugged in that has to be accessed manually.

Comment: Try to remember what option you changed for the drive.

Comment: Maybe review these steps - https://www.groovypost.com/howto/disable-manage-autoplay-external-devices-windows-10

Comment: What happens if you assing the stick a different drive letter and then remove it an stickt it back in? Will it keep that drive letter? Do you have any network drives?

Comment: Yes, mit keeps the new drive letter and continues to work.  Then when I stick another drive in, it defaults to E; and again doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
Unplug the drive(s) if it is plugged in.

Then:

Device Manager > View > Show hidden devices

Expand "Disk drives"

Right-click and select "Uninstall device" and uninstall all grayed out entries for the drive(s)

Close Device Manager and plug the drive back in

Comment: This solution worked for a while then stopped working.  So I mapped drive e: to an unused network address.  Now the system doesn't use E: and everything works.